# Python : How to format large number without comma

Tags: python, format

Problem is described below :

```
a = 535221324694    
b = round(a*1,024)    
print "number :"+str(b)    
>number :5.48066636487e+11
```

I have tried :

```
print "number :"+'{0:0f}'.format(b)
>number :548066636487.000000
```

The result I am looking for is :

```
>548066636487
```

Comment: there is a typo in your code, `b = round(a * 1.024)` instead of  `b = round(a*1,024)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use:

```
print "number : {0:.0f}".format(b)
```

the zero after dot determines how many decimal digits you want after the the decimal mark. :)

extra:
 you don't have to combine strings, just write them as one. It is easier to understand later.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `b` to int , then you dont need `0:0f` in `format` :

```
b = int(round(a*1,024))    
>>> "number :"+'{}'.format(b)
'number :535221324694'
```

or as says in comment you may dont need to use `format` :

```
print "number:", int(b)
```

Comment: Is there any need for the format string at all? Why not just `print "number:", int(b)`?

Comment: @tobias_k yes , i add it to answer to , thanks for reminding !

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to int e.g

print "number :"+ str(int(b))